# QML: Buttons of invisible screens still active?

Tags: qt, qml

I am developing a qml application for a touchscreen. The app is organized into different screens
e.g. in my `main.qml` looks like this

```
ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 1024
height: 600

Screen1 {
    id: screen1
    visible: true
}

Screen2 {
    id: screen2
    visible: false
}
```

I switch between these screens, through buttons, e.g. on Screen1 there would be a `mouseArea` which does

```
 onClicked: {
     screen1.visible=false
     screen2.visible=true
 }
```

I now wonder whether this is the way to do it, as I observe a strange behaviour: I have a button on screen2 which is at the same position as a button on screen1 (which triggers `Qt.quit()`. The button on screen2 most of the time does what it should. However, if I click several times on it, sometimes the quit button on screen1 is triggered (I explicitly checked with a `log.console` writeout), although this screen is invisible.

Why does this happen and how can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: 1. You could write a MVCE in which you isolate the problem. The good thing about MVCEs is, you often find minor mistakes yourself while writing them. And they help others to point out where your error might lie. 2. Instead of turning them `visible = false` you might stuff that stuff in a `Loader` and unload what is not necessary. Make sure to not store the state (valuable values in variables that should persist a change of screens) in the screen but in a seperate model then.

Comment: There is not enough code in the question to really identify the problem. Please include at least the `Buttons` and `MouseAreas` on each Screen

Comment: I would use a SwipeView. More infos here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qml-qt-labs-controls-swipeview.html

As of what is causing the problem, there no way to tell from just the code you posted

Comment: I will try to create a mvce

Comment: I fail to produce a mvce. But I guess the principle question is the following: Can a not visible screen receive keyboard or mouse input?

Comment: @numberCruncher: Did you find any solution for this ? I am facing same problem.